# Invalid results file Warning when running Azure DevOps Test Task

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-pipelines

I am using Azure DevOps to run some XUnit tests of an Asp.Net Core application:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Test'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*[Tt]est/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

The task succeeds but I get two warnings:

```
[warning] Invalid results file. Make sure the result format of the file '/home/vsts/work/_temp/_fv-az592_2019-04-09_21_14_05.trx' matches 'VSTest' test results format.
[warning] Invalid results file. Make sure the result format of the file '/home/vsts/work/_temp/_fv-az592_2019-04-09_21_14_10.trx' matches 'VSTest' test results format.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

From [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9292):

> warning is as per our design of task since we wants to warn customer
>   if he is trying to use PTR task without any results, but i agree with
>   you about more apt warning message and we will correct it in upcoming
>   release.

Also try yo use [VSTest task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops) instead

Comment: Is VSTest task a better option than DotNetCoreCLI@2 task with Test command? I am asking this as I though for ASP.NET core application it would be better to use  DotNetCoreCLI@2 task with its commands.

Comment: It doesn't actually matter VSTest task  means that it use the Visual Studio Test Runner